# Getting functions to interact with each other

Tags: python, python-3.x

The project: Write a program in python in which the virtual dealer Jake plays against the virtual players: Mike and Will. Mike and Will are free to bet on different outcomes with different payout ratios. This will allow the comparison of various strategies. You should keep track of each player's bank roll (including the dealer)
The game is played with a 7 faced die with numbers [0 - 6] numbers[1, 2, 3] are blue and numbers [4, 5, 6] are green.

Correct Parity Pays: 2/1
Correct Colour Pays: 2/1
Exact Number Pays: 5/1

Here is the first draft with the modifications @Harvey Summer suggested. Comments on how I can improve the code's structure and performance are appreciated.

```
from random import choice
from random import randint

class die_face():
    # This class is used to define the properties linked to each outcome on the dice.
    def __init__(self, num, colour, parity):
        self.num = num
        self.colour = colour
        self.parity = parity

# Determine the properties linked to each outcome on the dice.
zero = die_face(0, 'none', 'none')
one = die_face(1, 'blue', 'odd')
two = die_face(2, 'blue', 'even')
three = die_face(3, 'blue', 'odd')
four = die_face(4, 'green', 'even')
five = die_face(5, 'green', 'odd')
six = die_face(6, 'green', 'even')

options = [zero, one, two, three, four, five, six,]


class bet():
    # Define the bets
    def __init__(self, bet_type, odds):
        self.bet_type = bet_type
        self.odds = odds

num_bet = bet('num', 5)
colour_bet = bet('colour', 2)
parity_bet = bet('parity', 2)


class broker():
    # Define the properties of the broker.
    def __init__(self, name, balance):
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance

    def __str__(self):
        result = "Name:       {} \n" \
                 "Balance:    {}" .format(self.name, self.balance)
        return result


    def modify_balance(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount

main_broker = broker('Main',1e3)


def random_strategy():
    # Bet a random amount on a random game with a random guess.
    guess = 'empty'
    game_mode= choice([num_bet, colour_bet, parity_bet])
    if game_mode == num_bet:
        guess = randint(0,6)
    elif game_mode == colour_bet:
        guess = choice(['blue','green'])
    elif game_mode == parity_bet:
        guess = choice(['even','odd'])
    value = randint(1,10)
    return game_mode , value, guess


class player():
    # This class defines each player
        def __init__(self, name, strategy, bank_roll):
            self.name = name
            self.strategy = strategy
            self.bank_roll = bank_roll

        def modify_balance(self, amount):
            self.bank_roll += amount

        def __str__(self):
            result = "Name:       {} \n" \
                     "Bank Roll:  {}" .format(self.name, self.bank_roll)
            return result

        def play(self):
            return self.strategy()


# Add the players
Will = player("Will",random_strategy,100)


def dealer(type, bet_value, guess):
    #Roll the dice
    correct = choice(options)
    #Return amount based on Win or Lose
    if type == num_bet.bet_type:
        if correct.num == guess:
            return num_bet.odds * bet_value - bet_value
        else:
            return -bet_value

    if type == colour_bet.bet_type:
        if correct.colour == guess:
            return colour_bet.odds * bet_value - bet_value
        else:
            return -bet_value

    if type == parity_bet.bet_type:
        if correct.parity == guess:
            return parity_bet.odds * bet_value - bet_value
        else:
            return -bet_value

def main_play(player):
    # Collect the bets from the players
    bets = player.play()
    # Roll and return bets
    amount = dealer(bets[0].bet_type, bets[1], bets[2])
    # Distribute the money
    main_broker.modify_balance(amount*-1)
    player.modify_balance(amount)
print(player)
print(main_broker)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a bettingtable as a broker where money is put at risk and the outcome to the dealer and players are exchanged based on the play outcome, and allow players and dealer to place bet and collect winnings. Encapsulate betting logic to the players and abstracted it from a game rules class. Each player should have a risk tolerance or game play style (lame, aggressive, cheater, etc.)

If you build this right, it shouldn't matter what the game is: dice, cards, etc. should basically play the same.

Comment: So how would the said dealer and players interact in this? Would it be just a tool to keep track of the broker's transactions?

Comment: The bettingtable or board is what executes a play and acts as the holder of the funds during play. So: 1) place bets, 2) roll dice, 3) pay out based on outcome, repeat. Each player has a bet. The dealer bets 0 - its the table that pays out, not the dealer. (But the dealer has special rules to play by.) so the bettingtable is where the turn is executed. This makes a stable state-driven machine.